# Redshift: fetching data from sales table based on date bands from another table

Tags: sql, date, join, sum, amazon-redshift

My table t1 contains item and lead time (time for delivery of an item from supplier).
My table t2 contains datewise sale of the items in past 60 days.
I need to add a column to T1 with total sales from T2 in the past lead time days. In other words, I want to calculate lead time sales where lead time is different for each item. My tables are in Redshift.

T1

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      item_no        |     Lead Time    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    10002341         |         7        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    10002342         |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

T2

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      item_no        |   Date of sale   | Amount of Sale
|---------------------|------------------|
|    10002341         |   11-06-2020     |   $100
|---------------------|------------------|
|    10002341         |    12-06-2020    |   $200
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Please specify nontrivial sample input data and corresponding expected output. Also prefer using CTE (with clause) rather than plaintext tables to specify your input data. Or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I searched how to put tables in stackoverflow and got this. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow
Will learn dbfiddle and update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a lateral join:

```
select t1.*, x.*
from t1
left join lateral (
    select coalesce(sum(amount), 0) lead_amount
    from t2
    where 
        t2.item_no = t1.item_no 
        and t2.date_of_sale >= current_date - t1.lead_time * interval '1 day'
) x on true
```

If your database does not support lateral joins, then another option is a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t1.*, 
    (
        select coalesce(sum(amount), 0) 
        from t2
        where 
            t2.item_no = t1.item_no 
            and t2.date_of_sale >= current_date - t1.lead_time * interval '1 day'
    ) lead_amount
from t1
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. Redshift does not seem to support lateral joins yet. I have updated my tags.

Comment: Correlated subqueries worked! though it is painfully slow, but atleast i have my answer :)